# How to increase sound with a shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, audio, taskbar, keystrokes

I am on **Windows 10**, and I **don't want to install anything (like AHK).** I am wondering if I can get a shortcut on my taskbar that ticks up/down the sound by one. My computer is funky and when I press volume up, it goes up by 10, although I do not want any help changing this.

Specifically, I would like to **pin two shortcuts to my taskbar that increase/decrease the volume by 1 level.** I want it to increase **ONLY my headphones when they're plugged in** and not my speakers, because I only use headphones and never my speakers. The outcome I would want is **if my volume was at 7, I would press the increase shortcut pinned to my taskbar, it would go to 8, and vice versa.**

###### Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google knows>>>>https://www.alphr.com/adjust-audio-hotkeys-windows/

Comment: You cannot do this in Windows10 without using a third party solution (such as AutoHotKey)

Comment: @Mastaxx like not even with a powershell script? That's kind of surprising

Comment: It can be done with a powershell script but you are describing being able up/down your volume in 1 increments using an item pinned to your taskbar. Do this with powershell you would need to create your powershell script and then wrap it to exe form so it can become executable, because powershell scripts cannot be run without a right click > run with powershell.

Comment: @Mastaxx yes, but what is the PowerShell script that would work? I tried many different things, and I couldn't find a single working solution.

Comment: I don't know. You're best off trying to create the script yourself using examples you've found on the internet and then if you run into troubles post your script in your question and add powershell and script to your tags in the question to open it up to that superuser community

Comment: @Mastaxx But the thing is, I haven't found any talk of changing the volume in PowerShell. Nobody has this kind of problem. I will try to find out, though.

Comment: oh it's out there trust e